# Capybara: testing when cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage are disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs, capybara-webkit

Need help finding a way to write a test for cases where all or some of the following are disabled in the requesting browser:

- cookies
- localStorage
- sessionStorage

I have looked at capybara-webkit and poltergeist (PhantomJS) but neither seems to allow for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as disabling cookies in phantomjs via poltergeist in your test suite:

poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb line 243

contains a handy method that you can use like this:

```
page.driver.browser.cookies_enabled= false
```

Then you can visit a page that checks for cookies, and confirm your app's approach to asking for cookies from the user is working. I was able to turn cookies back on later in the test as well, and confirm the recovery part of my app's workflow. No re-start necessary.

```
page.driver.browser.cookies_enabled= true
```